# GWTCanvas doesn't work in IE8

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, internet-explorer-8

We heavily use GWTCanvas in our project and it work excellent.

Except for IE8 in its standard document mode.

To solve this we have tried:

1. Update gwt-incubator to the latest version (2.1.0)
2. Patch `GWTCanvas.java` according to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/7g0O2ar5MiI)

But this didn't help. Has anybody make it works on IE8? Working and reliable solution/approach would be much appreciated.

UPDATE

It has been solved in this way:

- [patch](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/tm/excanvas-patch/) `excanvas.js` and inject it into your GWT class
- replace `GWTCanvasImpl` with your class via deffered binding in proper `gwt.xml` file

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a Browser issue and not GWT. All solutions can only be a hack. Why don't you test if HTML5 (Canvas) is supported by the browser and if not inform the user that he needs to upgrage his browser?

Answer (score 1):

GWTCanvas uses the SVG specification to implement the vector objects on a given GWT site.

Although almost every other browser (Firefox, chrome and Opera and I am sure many others) have implemented the SVG one way or another, Ms does not support svg on a sufficient level yet.

Maybe including http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/ google javascript library implementation of SVG will solve your problems but then again it might not (have not tested it personally).

A different implementation of Vector Graphics fro GWT - gwt-graphics is another solution but again, if your vector objects are many, the emulation on IE gwt-graphics does make the applications not-responsive and just plain slow (personal experience).